# Post Magento 1.9 to 2.1 migration, cannot edit categories

Tags: category-products, magento2-migration-tool

Migrated using the official data migration tool and everything seems fine except we cannot edit product categories in the admin panel. Every change we attempt to save results in page spooling and an eventual service 500 page. Anyone else get something similar? Where should I look to fix this problem?